# Cleaning up After Tests for Swizzling function Swift

Tags: swift

I want to test the behavior of my App both when I invoke method swizzling, and when I don't.

```
class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: ViewController?
    override func setUp() {
        sut = ViewController()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
    }

    func testInitialLabelValue() {
        // without method swizzling engaged we pull from the existing strings
        sut?.viewDidLoad()
        XCTAssertEqual( sut?.targetLabel.text, "Welcome en lproj")
    }

    func testDownloaded() {
        // Strings from bundle
        sut?.viewDidLoad()
        Localizer.swizzleMainBundle()
        XCTAssertEqual( sut?.targetLabel.text, "Welcome en lproj")
    }
```

Now I'm not using tearDown() properly. How?

So how can I change this function to be testable?

```
let bundleName = "Bundle.bundle"

var downloadedBundlePath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: bundleName, ofType: nil)

class Localizer: NSObject {
    class func swizzleMainBundle() {
        MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: Bundle.self, originalSelector: #selector(Bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)), overrideSelector: #selector(Bundle.specialLocalizedStringForKey(_:value:table:)))
    }
}

extension Bundle {
    @objc func specialLocalizedStringForKey(_ key: String, value: String?, table tableName: String?) -> String {
        if self == Bundle.main {
            if let path = downloadedBundlePath, let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
                return (bundle.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName))
            }
            return (self.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName))
        } else {
            return (self.specialLocalizedStringForKey(key, value: value, table: tableName))
        }
    }
}

func MethodSwizzleGivenClassName(cls: AnyClass, originalSelector: Selector, overrideSelector: Selector) {
    if let origMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector), let overrideMethod: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, overrideSelector) {
        if (class_addMethod(cls, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
            class_replaceMethod(cls, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

Which needs to be testatable, but how since it is a function that needs to Swizzle

Comment: My Localizer swizzles NSLocalizedString and makes my tests fail. But that isn't important, I'm not cleaning up afterwards so I need to know how to .

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns do you want to reset Localizer after your test to defaults?

Comment: I Swizzle using Localizer.swizzleMainBundle() that swizzles NSLocalizedString. I don't know how to reset this and I'd expect to be able to do that by using something in tearDown()

Comment: This is explained https://qualitycoding.org/xctestcase-teardown/ but I don't know how to release all my objects to "start again"

Comment: It seems that you have to change `Localizer` to be testable because currently it is not.

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns you need to do exactly the opposite of what you do in swizzleMainBundle() method. You can write a class method reset() for class Localizer and in the method write the Swizzling code with parameters swapped for originalSelector and overrideSelector. This way you can reset. But for that you need to store references to the methods.